# Saving ID of product in cookies doesn't work for both languages wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, wpml

I have a wishlist page which shows all saved products. Products are saved in a cookie and that can be done through a click of a button when viewing a single product.

On that single product, there is an icon with two states, selected or unselected. The purpose is "Save for later". If the specific product is already in the cookie list then i add "selected" class, so the icon changes properly in order to let the user know that he already had "save for later" this product.

An example of cookie with 3 products : 185-589-382

That means we have three products with the ID's 185, 589, 382.

Every product has different ID for each language. That means a product in "EN"(english) has ID 100, but in the other language the ID may be 252.

Example :

Let's suppose i have only one product which has the ID 100 in "EN". That product, in the other language has the ID 200.

When visiting **mysite.com/wishlist** it shows the product in "EN" (defualt language)

When visiting **mysite.com/el/wishlist** it shows the product in "GR".

It works just fine even though they have different ID's. (probably because there is a connection between them through the plugin i am using)

**My problem**

When viewing a single product in "EN", which has the id 100, supposing that id is already in the cookie list - the icon has the selected state. When i press the language switcher, it switches to the other language showing the product but the icon is not in the selected state. I know this happens because in the cookie list i have saved the product with the id 100 (which is in "EN" only) and not 200 which is the other's language ID.

Is there any workaround?

**Using WPML Plugin.**

- Didn't post any code because i don't have a problem with the coding but if that's going to help you then feel free to ask.
- Currently searching a way to find how these posts are connected so maybe i change what i save into my cookie list. One way would be to save all the id's of each language but i would like to keep it clean - find the best way.

Comment: I think I would iterate over the array of wishlist IDs and check WPML language for that ID, if it differs from current selected language I would look up the corresponding page in the selected language and if that's the current page then show as in wishlist.

Remember to remove ID from all languages when you remove it as a wishlist item and probably check so you're not adding the same page in two different languages to your wishlist.

Comment: I am currenty using one list for all languages. Changed the checking a little bit to make it work - check answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using the below WPML function :

```
icl_object_id(get_the_ID(), 'post', false, ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
```

This function returns the post id of "ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE" - which means current language.

So, i stored in an array `$mLanguages` all the available languages. Then, used a for loop to store in `$mIDArray` all the ID's in every language of **current** product :

```
foreach($mLanguages as $language) {
    $mIDArray[] = icl_object_id($mCurrentPostID, 'post', false, $language);
}
```

Below is the code block which was checking if post id was in the cookie list **before** :

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mSavedList'])) {
    $mListOfSavedItems = $_COOKIE['mSavedList'];
    $mListOfSavedItems = explode('-', $mListOfSavedItems);

    if(in_array(get_the_ID(), $mListOfSavedItems))
        $isCurrentProductSaved = true;
}
```

`$isCurrentProductSaved` is the "selected" statement i was talking about. **So i changed it to** :

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mSavedList'])) {
    $mListOfSavedItems = $_COOKIE['mSavedList'];
    $mListOfSavedItems = explode('-', $mListOfSavedItems);

    foreach($mListOfSavedItems as $item){

        if($mCurrentPostID == $item)
            $isCurrentProductSaved = true;
        else if(in_array($item, $mIDArray))
            $isCurrentProductSaved = true;

    }
}
```

In other words :

Before i was checking if current post id exists in my cookie list. Now i am checking if current post id ( or all translatables ID's of this post) exists in my cookie list.

Found a bug though :

I was saving current post's id into the cookie list no matter the language. To make it work, i always save the posts id of "EN" which is the default language.